# What does subscript i mean in statistics in this context (table with values included)?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, standard-deviation, excel, regression-coefficients

[image: statistics table]

This has been driving me nuts for hours.  I cannot find information anywhere on the internet on what the formulas in the upper-right two cells mean.  The i subscript is throwing me off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subscript $i$ refers to this being the $i$-th $x$ or the $i$-th $y$ out of $n$. In your table it's basically row number. The third column is the difference between actual $y$ value for the $i$-th data point and the predicted $y$ value (by line of best fit) using the $i$-th $x$ value. This is typical use of the subscript $i$.

Take the first row for an example, also just assume that the first two columns said $x_i$ and $y_i$ because that's what's meant and maybe what it should have said from the beginning. So $i = 1$. We have $x_1 = 1, y_1 = 3.6$. The $y(x_i)$ is $y$ as a function of $x_i$, that is $0.564x_i + 2.14$, the line of best fit. If it were up to me I'd have called it $\hat y_i$ instead. So then
$$
y_i - y(x_i) = y_1 - y(x_1) = 3.6 - (0.564\cdot 1 + 2.14) = 0.896
$$
This is the error of your model. The last column is simply the square of the error.

An important question to this that I myself have: why does the text give two different lines as the line of best fit? The equation $0.564x + 2.14 = 0.564 + 2.14x$ is true if and only if $x=1$.

Comment: This is not to say that the notation in that table doesn't strike me as slightly strange

Comment: I still don't quite understand.  By i-th element, by what does it determine what i is to calculate the value in the corresponding table element?  Can you do the first row as an example so I can see where the numbers are being taken from?

Comment: The table itself is a bit confusing because they use the $i$ some places and not others, they don't use the $i$ for the first and second column, but basically you just use those values within that row. I've updated the answer where I work through row 1, hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you.  Can you tell me how the 1.1 was calculated?  The Cmax<Dmax<1.1 part.  I just need to know how they came up with 1.1.

Comment: Okay, now there's something else throwing me off.  Why is it row 7 is not calculated but instead rows 1 through 6 are summed to come up with the value in row 7?

Comment: You mean the $D = 0.70 \leq c_{max} \leq d_{max} \leq 1.02$? The text says it's the largest absolute deviation; it's the largest of the absolute values of column 3. As to the row 7 issue: I honestly have no idea.